# INotifyPropertyChanged and Threading

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, binding

I have a base class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
protected void OnNotifyChanged(string pName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

I have a derived class with a property `Latitude` like so:

```
private double latitude;

public double Latitude
{
    get { return latitude; }
    set { latitude = value; OnNotifyChanged("Latitude"); }
}
```

My derived class also has a method `Fly` that manipulates `Latitude`.

I also have a Form with a TextBox bound to `Latitude` of my derived class:

```
txtLat.DataBindings.Clear();    
txtLat.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindSrc, "Latitude");
```

A thread is used to kick off `Fly` like so:

```
Thread tFly = new Thread(f.Fly);
tFly.IsBackground = true;
tFly.Start();
```

When `Latitude` changes, an exception is thrown:

`DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an odd issue with thread affinity. Ultimately, the code is trying to do the update from a non-UI thread - I'm unclear why it isn't just displaying the cross-thread exception, though - I wonder whether this is actually a catch-all exception handler. If I remove the `BindingSource` (and bind directly to the object, which is valid) you **do** get a cross-thread exception (which I expected).

*Personally*, I would be inclined to handle this manually, i.e. subscribe to the event with a method that does an `Invoke` to the UI thread and updates the `Text` manually. However, I'm just checking if some previous cross-threaded binding code might help...

---

Here's an example using `Invoke`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class FlightUav : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnNotifyChanged(string pName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private double _latitude;
    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude; }
        set { _latitude = value; OnNotifyChanged("Latitude"); }
    }
    public void Fly()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Latitude++;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            FlightUav currentlyControlledFlightUav = new FlightUav();

            currentlyControlledFlightUav.PropertyChanged += delegate
            { // this should be in a *regular* method so that you can -= it when changing bindings...
                form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    form.Text = currentlyControlledFlightUav.Latitude.ToString();
                });
            };


            using (Button btn = new Button())
            {
                btn.Text = "Fly";
                btn.Click += delegate
                {
                    Thread tFly = new Thread(currentlyControlledFlightUav.Fly);
                    tFly.IsBackground = true;
                    tFly.Start();
                };
                form.Controls.Add(btn);
                Application.Run(form);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

---

Here's an example using a (modified) version of some old threading code of mine:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class FlightUav : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnNotifyChanged(string pName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private double _latitude;
    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude; }
        set { _latitude = value; OnNotifyChanged("Latitude"); }
    }
    public void Fly()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Latitude++;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            FlightUav currentlyControlledFlightUav = new FlightUav();
            BindingSource bindSrc = new BindingSource();
            var list = new ThreadedBindingList<FlightUav>();
            list.Add(currentlyControlledFlightUav);
            bindSrc.DataSource = list;

            form.DataBindings.Clear();
            form.DataBindings.Add("Text", list, "Latitude");

            using (Button btn = new Button())
            {
                btn.Text = "Fly";
                btn.Click += delegate
                {
                    Thread tFly = new Thread(currentlyControlledFlightUav.Fly);
                    tFly.IsBackground = true;
                    tFly.Start();
                };
                form.Controls.Add(btn);
                Application.Run(form);
            }
        }
    }


}
public class ThreadedBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext ctx;
    public ThreadedBindingList()
    {
        ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }
    protected override void OnAddingNew(AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        SynchronizationContext ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        if (ctx == null)
        {
            BaseAddingNew(e);
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.Send(delegate
            {
                BaseAddingNew(e);
            }, null);
        }
    }
    void BaseAddingNew(AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnAddingNew(e);
    }
    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ctx == null)
        {
            BaseListChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.Send(delegate
            {
                BaseListChanged(e);
            }, null);
        }
    }
    void BaseListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnListChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @WulfgarPro added two *different* examples

Comment: @WulfgarPro - yes, I was simply being brief with the example - limiting it to the bare minimum that would show *something* happening.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I've successfully got the Invoke example working. I'll admit I'm still quite novice when it comes to delegates and event handling. I've tried a few things but I keep coming up with a `Cannot access a disposed object named "FormName"` exception when trying to exit my application. Any ideas ?

Comment: @WulfgarPro it *sounds* like the thread is still running, causing the callback. You should unsubscribe it when closing the form.

Comment: @wulfgar I'll look tomorrow - can you @Marc me again now to remind me?