# What are C# lambda's compiled into? A stackframe, an instance of an anonymous type, or?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, lambda

What are C# lambda's compiled into? A stackframe, an instance of an anonymous type, or?

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687942/why-cant-c-sharp-use-inline-anonymous-lambdas-or-delegates).  Which mostly answers "why" you can't use a lambda when also using implicit type features.  But, this question is aimed at answering what construct the compiler produces to actually carry out the code of a lambda.  Is it a method call of an anonymous type (something like anonymous types that implement an interface in Java?) or is it just a stack frame with references to closed variables and the accepting the parameter signature?  Some lambda's don't close over anything -- so are there then 2 different resulting outputs from the compile.

Comment: There are actually two completely different implementations - is it a delegate? Or an expression-tree?

Comment: Probably an expression tree is what I'm after here:
    (x) => x.ToString()
something like that.  I'm guessing a delegate is actually an instance of a type because of the +=, and what not.

Comment: @lucidquier the syntax is identical; you can't tell what it is unless you know the type of the assignment or parameter type.

Comment: Jon has excellent coverage of this topic in C# in Depth - it isn't trivial, so I do recommend: read the chapter in there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you mean "as a delegate", then it still depends :p if it captures any variables (including "this", which may be implicit) then those variables are actually implemented as fields on a compiler-generated type (not exposed anywhere public), and the statement body becomes a method on that capture class. If there are multiple levels of capture, the outer capture is again a field on the inner capture class. But essentially:

```
int i = ...
Func<int,int> func = x => 2*x*i;
```

Is like;

```
var capture = new SecretType();
capture.i = ...
Func<int,int> func = capture.SecretMethod;
```

Where:

```
class SecretType {
    public int i;
    public int SecretMethod(int x) { return 2*x*i; }
}
```

This is identical to "anonymous methods", but with different syntax.

Note that methods that do not capture state may be implemented as static methods without a capture class.

Expression trees, on the other hand... Are trickier to explain :p

But (I don't have a compiler to hand, so bear with me):

```
int i = ...
Expression<Func<int,int>> func = x => 2*x*i;
```

Is something like:

```
var capture = new SecretType();
capture.i = ...
var p = Expression.Parameter("x", typeof(int));  
Expression<Func<int,int>> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,int>>(
    Expression.Multiply(
        Expression.Multiply(Expression.Constant(2),p),
        Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(capture), "i")
    ), p);
```

(except using the non-existent "memberof" construct, since the compiler can cheat)

Expression trees are complex, but can be deconstructed and inspected - for example to translate into TSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are indeed anonymous functions, but with more versatility.  These two articles authored by the MSDN have a lot of information on lambda expressions, how to use them, what precedence the operator `=>` has, what their relation to anonymous functions are, and some advanced suggestions of use.

[Lambda Expressions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[=> Operator (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples:

```
public class C
{
    private int field = 0;

    public void M()
    {
        int local = 0;

        Func<int> f1 = () => 0;
        // f1 is a delegate that references a compiler-generated static method in C

        Func<int> f2 = () => this.field;
        // f2 is a delegate that references a compiler-generated instance method in C

        Func<int> f3 = () => local;
        // f3 is a delegate that references an instance method of a compiler-generated nested class in C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is an unnamed method written in place of delegate istance. 
The compiler converts it to either:

- A ***delegate instance***
- An ***expression tree***, of type **`Expression<TDelegate>`** that representing the code inside, in a traversable object model. This allows the lambda expression to be interpreted at runtime.

So the compiler solves lambda expressions moving the expression's code into a private method.