# Do c# lambdas exist only at compile time?

Tags: c#, lambda

Am I right in saying that lambda expressions exist only at compile time, and once compiled they become either an Expression (LambdaExpression?) or a delegate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993426/what-are-c-sharp-lambdas-compiled-into-a-stackframe-an-instance-of-an-anonymo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. In addition to a delegate, lambdas become a generated method. The delegate refers to that method. If they close over variables, the method becomes an instance method on a generated class holding the closure state.

In that sense you can use a lambda and local variables to create a class with fields and one method, similar to JavaScript.