# How to work around not being able to use refs in a lambda?

Tags: c#, interop, ref, callable

I'm writing a wrapper around some C code, and I can't quite figure out how to write this bit without being able to use the [`ref` keyword in a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions).

The unmanaged function wrappers look like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate int SDL_EventFilter(ref object userData, ref SDL_Event @event);

[DllImport("SDL2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SDL_AddEventWatch")]
internal static extern void SDL_AddEventWatch(SDL_EventFilter filter, ref object userData);
```

But I don't want to use `SDL_Event` directly (it's a complicated struct), so I've wrapped it in my own class, `Event`. However, C is expecting a pointer to an `SDL_Event` not an `Event` so I have to write some more code to wrap it all up:

```
public delegate void EventFilter(object userData, Event @event);

public static void AddEventWatch(EventFilter filter, object userData)
{
    SDL_AddEventWatch((ref data, ref e) =>        // <-- can't do this
    {
        filter(data, new Event(ref e));
        return 0;
    }, ref userData);
}
```

This basically takes the `SDL_Event` that I'm given and converts it into my `Event` class. However, I can't use the `ref` keyword inside a lambda, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

I could define a regular helper method instead of using a lambda, but I need to use the local `filter` variable inside of it, and I don't know how to get that into the function without changing the signature (then it wouldn't match `SDL_EventFilter`).

In JavaScript, PHP, or Python I could construct a callable object, make `filter` a member variable, and then use the object as the callback. I'm not sure if there's a similar concept in C#, is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `ref` keyword, the type must also be given. Like this:

```
(ref object data, ref SDL_Event e) => { ... }
```

The parameter list of a lambda is like the parameter list of an ordinary named method. The types can be left out in a lambda, however, but only when no parameters have modifyers such as `ref`, `out`, `params`.

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't mentioned in the bug I linked to, but syntactically this compiles. It, however, causes an exception but that has something to do with passing it off to the DLL. I will have to investigate that further, but I reckon this answers the question as posed. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark The question you linked was also about "capturing" `ref` parameters from an ordinary "named" method inside a lambda. As in this example `public object NamedMethod(ref int i) { Func<int> lambda = () => i; return lambda; }`. Here the lambda introduces no `ref` itself, but it tries to capture a `ref` parameter from the containing method. There's no chance this could compile since the compiler won't know what to capture, really. But that is different from the situation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can't do it since `Lambda` actually captures the variable in `CompilerGenerated` class and reuses it.

We can make use of `ref` keyword while passing to a method, but still if you capture the parameter to someother variable `It wont behave as you expect`.

So easy workaround will be create a method and use instead of lambda.

Comment: I addressed that, 2nd to last paragraph. How can I write a method? The method has to match the signature of `SDL_EventFilter`, but it can't if I want to pass in `filter`.

Comment: @Mark You need signature to be same as 2 parameter? if not you can create one more parameter right?

Comment: You need to write a class to capture the `filter`.  In general, this is how lambdas are implemented by the compiler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993426/what-are-c-sharp-lambdas-compiled-into-a-stackframe-an-instance-of-an-anonymo

Comment: @lukegravitt: That would be my last paragraph. Is there an MSDN article on doing that? I didn't know this was possible in C#. Edit: I think you edited in a link. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can use `Tuple` instead of custom class

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: What do you mean a `Tuple`? Tuples aren't callable...??

Comment: I mean you can wrap any type inside Tuple and pass to method right? like this `Tuple<Class1, object> tuple = Tuple.Create<Class1, object>(new Class1(), new object());` To avoid creating custom class for this.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No...the method has a very specific signature. It has to match what's defined in C.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```
class Capture
{
    private readonly EventFilter filter;

    public Capture(EventFilter filter)
    {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public int Method(ref object userData, ref SDL_Event @event)
    {
        this.filter(userData, new Event(ref event));
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void AddEventWatch(EventFilter filter, object userData)
{
    var capture = new Capture(filter);
    SDL_AddEventWatch(capture.Method, ref userData);
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I need :-) Will try this out in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't quite work out like I hoped. I'm getting an exception: "An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss."

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't like using refs in unmanaged code either. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to get around that.

Comment: It's not the refs, they behave like pointers AFAIK. I think the problem is passing a managed class to an unmanaged DLL. I asked a question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18096415/65387).