# Closure and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, closures

```
IEnumerable<char> charQuery1 = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
   charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != vowels[i]);
foreach (char c in charQuery1) Console.Write(c);
```

This is will throw IndexOutofRange Exception. Compiler scopes the for loop variable "i" as like declared outside. Can someone dissect this and make me more comfortable to understand? Debugging did not help me much here. I am trying to understand the compiler role here.

Comment: not answering your question but this would be the correct way: `charQuery1 = charQuery1.Except(vowels)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Sorry wrong link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: You need to copy the loop variable inside the loop

Comment: This answer helps to understand the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993720/284240 The loop variable `i` will be transferred to a field in a class. It's value is increased in the loop until 5, the foreach will execute the query with the final value 5.

Answer (score 3):

Linq functions such as `Where` create an IEnumerable that will be *lazily* evaluated.

This means the result of the `Where` function will not be produced when the `Where` function is being invoked. The result of the `Where` function is being produced when the *IEnumerable* returned by `Where` is being iterated.

In your example code, the results of the `Where` functions are iterated in the *foreach* loop at the end of your code:

```
foreach (char c in charQuery1) Console.Write(c);
```

This is where the enumerabled returned by the `Where` functions are being iterated, causing the predicate delegates provided to the `Where` functions to be executed.

In your case, those predicate delegate are anonymous functions in the form of `c => c != vowels[i]`, which close over the variable `i`.

Once again, those anonymous functions `c => c != vowels[i]` are invoked only when the
*foreach* loop at the end of your code is being executed.

So, what is the value of `i` when the *foreach* loop is being executed? It's the last value it has when the `for` loop exits. In other words, the value of `i` is equal to `vowels.Length`.

That leads to the predicate delegate to be equivalent to `c => c != vowels[vowels.Length]`. Obviously, `vowels[vowels.Length]` will cause an IndexOutOfRangeException.

How to fix it?

The naive approach would be to not let your predicates close over the `i` counter variable of the *for* loop. Instead, let it close over a variable that is scoped **inside** the *for* body:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
{
    var local_i = i;
    charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != vowels[local_i]);
}
```

But as the comment by Tim Schmelter points out, the more elegant and much shorter solution would be to simply use Linq's `Except` method:

```
var charQueryWithoutVowels = charQuery1.Except(vowels);
```

Comment: Very detail and clear explanation, but it give to possibility to look on closure Lambda from other point, thanks it help me. But another elegant solution to use the foreach vs for `            foreach (var itemChar in vowels) charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != itemChar);`

Answer (score 0):

The predicate you pass into `Where` (which is `c != vowels[i]`) is executed in deferred way when you enumerate charQuery1 in last part of the code (`foreach (char c in charQuery1)`). By that moment variable `i` has the value which was the last one in the loop `for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)` which is '5'. So you  captured the value which is modified from inner closure.
You must remember that LINQ expressions have deferred execution and don't execute when you declare them but when you enumerate them.

To avoid this problem you should capture loop index into temporary variable withing the loop scope like this.

```
IEnumerable<char> charQuery1 = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
{
   int index = i; // Temporary index variable. Should be declared inside the scope!
   charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != vowels[index]);
}
foreach (char c in charQuery1) Console.Write(c);
```

UPD: Fully deferred behavior:

```
IEnumerable<char> charQuery1 = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";
Enumerable
    .Range(0, vowels.Length)
    .ForEach(i =>
    {
        charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != vowels[i]);
    });
foreach (char c in charQuery1) Console.Write(c);
```

But even further simplification will give you this:

```
IEnumerable<char> charQuery1 = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";

charQuery1 = Enumerable
    .Range(0, vowels.Length)
    .Aggregate(charQuery1, (cq, i) => cq.Where(c => c != vowels[i]));

foreach (char c in charQuery1) Console.Write(c);
```

Cool, isn't it?

Comment: Can you explain deferred execution in little more detail? When I enumerate and print, doesn't it goes to for loop again? if i=5 then it should never execute. right?

Comment: @Jeevan  The `for` loop is executed immediately but LINQ expressions are executed only when enumerated. In your example you have mix of these two behaviors and that's the cause of the problem. Id suggest to stick with complete deferred behavior and replace your first loop with this:

`Enumerable
    .Range(0, vowels.Length)
    .ForEach(i =>
    {
        charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != vowels[i]);
    });`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was confused with. Immediate execution of for loop and deferred execution of delegate. Now I am clear. TY

Comment: It will work but not so elegant as more simple solution  ` foreach (var itemChar in vowels) charQuery1 = charQuery1.Where(c => c != itemChar);`. The term "Fully deferred behavior" is strange because "fully" or "not fully" change nothing