# how can i use Messagebox.Show in async method on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Exception generated on `MessageBox`. How can I use `MessageBox` in `async` method?

```
private async void Purchheard(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Начинаю покупку");
    try
    {
        await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(ID,false);
        if(license.ProductLicenses[ID].IsActive)
        {
            world.is_freemium=false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show("whatever"));`

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("whatever")); Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { MessageBox.Show("your stuff"); });
```

Comment: @gayan1991 Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate because it is not a delegate type... Does not work as proposed.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why the accepted answer doesn't work, but here is a working example for .NET 4.5

```
var dg = new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(msg, name); });
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(dg);
```

[Anonymous methods and delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968709/anonymous-methods-and-delegates)

[CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi)

Comment: I also had a requirement not to block the main thread and this worked nicely for me.