# In Silverlight, how to make program sleep without occupying thread

Tags: multithreading, silverlight

I have a case that need embed a background sleep in a for loop.
is there any way to do it without breakout the shape of for loop?

```
for (;;)
{
    Dosomething();
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // this blocks the UI thread, hope to find someway to sleep in background
}
```

-------------edited--------------

in Dosomething(), there is some UI thread operations like listBoxA.width += 5 (without dispatcher); 
Here the UI doesn't refresh until all the loop finishes.
the reason I want to use Sleep is I want to see the UI refresh each Dosomething is executed, like a animation.

Comment: You should explain more what you want to achieve - are you doing a polling or messaging loop? You could run the whole loop on a background thread, but there is no purpose or logic to a background sleep in a foreground (UI) thread.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307929/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-msgwaitformultipleobjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide much info for what you need your code, so I'll give it a try with this:

```
        int counter = 4;
        DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            DoSomething();

            counter--;

            if (counter == 0) _timer.Stop();

        };
        _timer.Start();
```

Comment: +1 although since the loop in the question is infinite I would not have included the counter here would make this code example much simpler.

Comment: @Rumplin, as I edited on my thread, actually I am trying to do some UI operation in Dosomething(), and use the for loop to achieve animation effect.  anyway I managed to do this using the time ticker.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Silverlight should be designed to run asynchronously. Your example is simply not the way to run regular background tasks in Silverlight (which is presumably is what your want `DoSomething()` to do).

Try reading up on [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to run your tasks on another thread generally and [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to run regular tasks (as Rumplin suggested in his example).