# Unresolved lambda expression in Re#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, lambda, resharper

I can't figure out what Re# is complaining about with a piece of code. Everything compiles ok and works as it should, but Re# can't seem to resolve the expression without offering any suggestions. Look at the attachment for code and error.

Any offers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. This was a bug in Resharper, now fixed in version 5.1.

Had the same warning all over the place (to the extent I turned off Re# until I got the 5.1 update). Ours was also a Silverlight 4 app.

Re# 5.1 behaves a lot better with VS 2010 now. Clashes with intellisense autocomplete have also vanished.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Resharper so I could be off the mark here, but Invoke accepts a Delegate or an Action; a lambda expression can be converted to either of those (as explained in [this answer from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411579/why-must-a-lambda-expression-be-cast-when-supplied-as-a-plain-delegate-parameter/411597#411597)).  Perhaps Resharper doesn't know *which* of those it should be cast to.

If you change it to

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => // ...
```

the error will most likely go away.

Comment: nice try, but Action requires a type parameter like Action<T>. What is T here?

Comment: @danijels: It only requires a parameter in .NET 2.0; 3.5+ include the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) type without the parameter.  You can obtain the plain Action by using [LinqBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), or you can use a MethodInvoker as described in [this answer from Marc Gravell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253138/anonymous-method-in-invoke-call/253150#253150).

Comment: I still can't get it to satisfy Re#. Your suggestion will compile just as fine as the original code, but Re# still pops up asking me to include the type parameter. I should also mention this is VS2010 and a Silverlight 4 project.

Comment: It was an educated guess.  I'm going to mark the answer as CW because it's still relevant to the discussion, but it's not *the* answer to the question.