# Cross thread operation not valid when use backgroundworker

Tags: c#

Below is my coding:

```
    Form2 msgForm;
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        //bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        msgForm = new Form2();

        try
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            msgForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox15.Text == "")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Please select Printer ID.", "Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //return;
        }
        // Coding that transmit protocol and will last around 2 minutes.
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        msgForm.Close();
    }
```

When I run this background worker coding, there's an error stating "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBox15' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

How do I solve this problem guys?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx):

```
// InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
// calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
// If these threads are different, it returns true.
if (this.comboBox15.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {if (comboBox15.Text == ""){// What you want to do}});
}
else
{
    if (comboBox15.Text == "")
    {
    }
}
```

also read the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx
[Anonymous method in Invoke call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253138/anonymous-method-in-invoke-call)

Answer (score 1):

You can't UI elements from a non-UI-thread. Ideally, provide the relevant information to the background worker before it starts, e.g.

```
string text = combo15.Text;
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => TransmitStuff(combo15.Text, args);

...

void TransmitStuff(string printerId, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

If you can use .NET 4.5 and C# 5, you could use an async method to quite possibly make all of this easier... but I realize that's unlikely to be an option for you.

EDIT: While you *can* use `Invoke`, that ends up being quite messy - and you've got potentially inconsistent state. I generally think it's tidier to work out *all* the state you need before you start the long-running operation, validate it all, and then hand it to the operation. If you need to update the UI during the operation, you can use the `BackgroundWorker` progress facilities.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought read operations were fine from a non-UI thread, aren't they?

Comment: @Rotem: Nope, that's still invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In BackgroundWorker, when we call any user controls its problem. Please use this property in Window Form Load event:

```
 CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access gui controls from your main thread.

Move the

> if (comboBox15.Text == "")

part to button3_click

Comment: But Thomsen, I need to use the value in comboBox15 during transmitting protocol. How?

Answer (score 0):

You can get round it by passing the value such as below.

```
private void Dowork()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox1.Text);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    String selected = (String)e.Argument;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(selected)) return;
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: BudFinder, I'm using your answer and can run perfectly. But my form will freeze when the backgroundworker is running. How to solve it?

Comment: Mine didnt.. Failing that, set a string to the value of the combo box, pass that, and remember all code in your "dowork" routine must reference the passed string, not the combo box...