# Can not assign value for textbox in backgroundworker (c# winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, backgroundworker

```
public class Form1
{
    public delegate void SetStatus (string status);
    public event SetStatus SetStatusHandler;

    public BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        tbxResult.Text = "Assign text Ok";

        SetStatusHandler += delegate(string status)
            {
                tbxResult.Text = status; // can not assign
            };

        bw.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var status = "assign some value";
        SetStatusHandler(status);
    }
}
```

First, I tried to set value for the textbox tbxResult on main thread inside BackgroundWorker, but it did not work, then I use delegate to assign the textbox value from main thread, but it does not work too...

Please help me... what was wrong?

Comment: You do not try to set it from main thread. Calling a delegate does not switch the thread. Set `backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`, subscribe to `backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event and call `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` instead of `SetStatusHandler`. Btw: backgroundworker is kind of obsolete, try to use `async/await` instead.

Comment: You should call `Control.Invoke` for this purpose. Read for more detail
[Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to invoke the method again using the main UI thread. Take a look for more info [Usage of MethodInvoker in C#](http://thebrainyprofessionals.com/2013/03/30/usage-of-methodinvoker-in-c/)

```
tbxResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
        tbxResult.Text = status;
    });
```

Comment: Its better to write some description too.

Comment: Yes, we need to invoke the method again using the main UI thread. Take a look for more info [Usage of MethodInvoker in C#](http://thebrainyprofessionals.com/2013/03/30/usage-of-methodinvoker-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope that logic make sense. But the declaration of delegate is wrong you have to specify the return type in the declaration of `SetStatus` to make it work. So change the declaration like the following:

```
public delegate void SetStatus (string status);
```

Still you are getting exception(`IllegalCrossThreadCallException` as `René Vogt` mentioned in the comment) means you can define the event handler like the following:

```
SetStatusHandler += delegate(string status)
 {
     tbxResult.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
     {
         tbxResult.Text = status;
     }));

 };
```

Comment: @RenéVogt: But it will update the text box with `"assign some value"`

Comment: The context of problem is different.

Comment: @un-lucky: Thank you! Could you tell me the difference between "tbxResult.text = status" and "tbxResult.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate...". The first is executed in backgroundworker thead and the second is on main thread, right?

Comment: @HoàngTrầnHuy: which will `Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.` see the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In general I think `BackgroundWorker` is obsolete and it's better to use the `async/await` pattern. But that would be too broad an answer.

So the immediate answer is: your event handler is not executed on the UI thread, but still on the background worker's thread. The normal way to reinvoke actions on the ui thread from a background worker is to use it's `ReportProgress` method:

```
public Form1()
{
    tbxResult.Text = "Assign text Ok";
    bw.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => tbxResult.Text = (string)e.UserState;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var status = "assign some value";
    bw.ReportProgress(0, status);
}
```

[`ReportProgress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) invokes the [`ProgressChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the **UI** thread, so you can assign text to your textbox. Remember to set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use InvokeRequred like this ( or with your delegate):

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { textBox1.Text = @"AAAAAA"; });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = @"AAAAAA";
        }
    }
```

ps: also see [Anonymous method in Invoke call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253138/anonymous-method-in-invoke-call)