# Changing control properties from background thread .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How to invoke changes to control from a background thread?

I used the code below for controls using .NET CF 3.5 but how to do it in .NET 2.0?

```
if (button2.InvokeRequired)
{
    button2.Invoke((Action)(() => button2.Enabled = true));
}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: What is the problem exactly? [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.80).aspx) is available in 2.0, [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.80).aspx) too. Seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253150/1997232) ?

Comment: @Sinatr Yes i pretty much needed to use MethodInvoker and all went well. Thank You